# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Actually we are not using any DB pool in certain fucntionalities  and we using JDBC to connect the postgres db,Currently the system in production and it was working without any issues but all of sudden we encountered following error.

Our configurations are fine because this error we got yesterday only.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone guess what is going on our production server?

Comment: Did you change *anything* yesterday?

Comment: Check to see if the file is still there on the application classpath, as Thilo suggested, something might have changed, server maintenance, accidental deletion, anything. Assuming this is a production server error, resolving the error takes priority I presume :)

Comment: You have done mistake in db name and db URL . So please give the complete code

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the `postgresql` driver and add it to your classpath.

Comment: Maybe someone deleted the jar on production server *by accident*

Comment: Have you changed anyting yesterday?

Comment: No , Actually this system is in production more than 3 years and all jar is in  place perfectly. All work till yesterday morning..

Comment: @user3020865 Is the server restarted or the process running the db query?